# Laravel: Dynamically fetch orders used in query?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to create a generic `success` method that parses my queries and auto sets some response data.

```
$items = Item::query()
   ->where('blah', $req->('blah_filter')
   ->orderBy('name', 'desc')
   ->paginate();

return success($items, 'yay, some results');
```

So far it's working fine,

BUT, I would also like to return the "order" used. Is there any way to sniff that out of a `paginate` or `get` collection? A list of orders?

**EDIT: By order, I mean from the `orderBy`** not related models.

For example with Paginator collection we can return:

```
return [
    'total' => $items->total(),
    'per_page' => $items->perPage(),
    'current_page' => $items->currentPage(),
    'items' => $items->items()
];
```

BUT can't seem to get the ordering used in the query:

```
return [
    'order' => $items->someCallHere()
];

// trying to return something like this:

[
    'order' => [
        'by' => 'name',
        'direction' => 'desc'
    ]
]
```

Comment: Is the "Item" owned by a "order" model? And you want to get the "orders" along with the "Items"?

Comment: @Mtxz check edit please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to slightly change the code you have.

Remove the `paginate()` from the end since you first want to get the orderings.
Add it afterwards in order to retrieve the `items`.

```
$items = Item::query()
   ->where('blah', $req->('blah_filter')
   ->orderBy('name', 'desc');

// in order to get the ordering used you can use:
$ordering = $items->getQuery()->orders;

// do something with $ordering

// this will be an array like this:
/**
array:1 [▼
  0 => array:2 [▼
    "column" => "created_at"
    "direction" => "desc"
  ]
]
*/

return success($items->paginate(), 'yay, some results');
```

Comment: yea, I've done it with query builder before, but that's messy, just wanna dump my results through something like a "response" builder.